# Can I get outcome from a formula to be send in a confirmation mail with google forms?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms, confirmation

I've made the following script with a google form:

```js
function myfunction (e){
            var Naam = e.values[1] //column b - works fine
            var Adres = e.values[2] //column c - works fine
            var Postcode = e.values[3] //column d - works fine
            var Woonplaats = e.values[4] //column e - works fine
            var Email = e.values[5] //column f - works fine
            var Aantal = e.values[6] //column g - works fine
            var Totaal = e.values[9] //column j - doesn't work
            var Verzendmethode = e.values[11] //column l - doesn't work
            var subject = "Bestelling kaarten Getup Standup"
            var message = "Beste " + Naam + ",\n\nBedankt voor uw bestelling de "
                          + Aantal + " kaarten " + Verzendmethode + " wanneer u "
                          + Totaal + " EURO over maakt op rekeningnr.
                            nl1ABNA1234567890\n\nHartelijk dank voor uw bestelling en
                            wij wensen u vast een prettige avond"

            MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, message);
}
```

Where the value of column j[9] is the outcome of multiplying the value of column g[6] times 5 and adding up the value of column i[8] (which is either 0 or 2,5) depending on the choice in a multiple choice question.

The value of column l[11] is a predefined text, also depending on the choice in a multiple choice question.

Within the spreadsheet everything works correct. I just want to use the values of column j and l within the confirmation mail that goes out to the visitor. Instead it now states undefined.

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908493/passing-custom-spreadsheets-column-to-onformsubmit-trigger) are relevant here.